# Sessions and Cookies Retrieving first and last name Welcome msg

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies

Trying to work on this program where it should in theory retrieve both the first and last name to a "Welcome" lblMessage. Working with Cookies in ASP.NET.

What it **IS** doing is just retrieving the [*"FirstName"*] only. I need ***both*** of them.

Order.aspx.cs

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

  string firstName = (string)Session["FirstName"];
    string lastName = (string)Session["LastName"];
    if ((firstName != null) && (lastName != null))
    {
        lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome back, " + (string)Session["FirstName"] + (string)Session[" LastName"] + "!";
    }
```

}

CheckOut.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get entry data from cookies
    //if (Request.Cookies["FirstName"] != null)
    //    txtFirstName.Text = Request.Cookies["FirstName"].Value;
    //if (Request.Cookies["LastName"] != null)
    //    txtLastName.Text = Request.Cookies["LastName"].Value;

    //get entry data from session state
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string firstName = (string)Session["FirstName"];
        if (firstName != null) txtFirstName.Text = (string)Session["FirstName"];
        string lastName = (string)Session["LastName"];
        if (lastName != null) txtLastName.Text = (string)Session["LastName"];
        txtFirstName.Focus();
    }
}

private void LoadCustomerData()
{
    Session["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    Session["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text;  
}
```

In a couple of sections [w/o displaying the entire code] this is what I have thus far.

Wondering if someone could set a pair of new eyes on this and see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely candidate is going to be a typo, which is hard to catch without looking at all of the code. I would recommend removing the "Magic Strings" (ie `Session["FirstName"]`) and declare some constants for the session variable names:

```
[in some static class]
public const string FirstNameKey = "FirstName";
public const string LastNameKey = "LastName";
```

and then refer consistently to those keys:

```
Session[FirstNameKey] = txtFirstName.Text;
```

I actually usually use GUIDs for the names (eg `public const string FirstNameKey = "49b63214-1812-4ba3-9ace-ae423c682d7c";` so that there's no irsk of repeating them through the application

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a type in the name of the cookie: `Session[" LastName"]`

Instead of

`string firstName = (string)Session["FirstName"];
... = (string)Session["FirstName];`

use

`string firstName = (string)Session["FirstName"];
... = firstName;`